# Visual Studio Multiple startup projects - restart one project only

Tags: visual-studio, startup

I have multiple projects running and one project sometimes stops and needs to be restarted.  Is there a way to restart only one project without stopping the other projects?  i.e., clicking the Restart button in Visual Studio that restarts all of the projects, but I only want to restart one.

Answer (score 1):

Independently from startup settings, each project can be started "manually" via: `right click on the project > Debug > Start New Instance`